# GuzzleHttp отправка JSON файла без предварительного сохранение его

Tags: php, fileupload

Хочется чтобы обработчик ошибок отправлял мне в Телеграм файл `.json` с выводом данных объекта `Exception`.

Чтобы отправить какой-то файл через `GuzzleHttp` нужно предворительно его создать. Но можно ли обойтись как-то одной функцией которая создавала файл не сохраняя его с расширением `.json` и определенным контентом? Что-то подобное `tmpfile()`

Answer (score 1):

Совсем необязательно создавать .json-файл, чтобы затем читать его и посылать через GuzzleHttp. Можно сразу прочитать .json-данные в переменную и отослать её содержимое, используя опцию `GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON`. Например, вот так:

```
$response = $client->request('PUT', '/put', ['json' => ['foo' => 'bar']]);
```

Обратите внимание, что данные отсылаются в виде ассоциированного массива, так что нужно их сначала перекодировать в массив при помощи `json_decode($json_data, true)`.

[Вот здесь подробности (англ.)](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json)

Если уж нужно соблюсти требования вопроса, то с большой вероятностью задачу решат потоки ввода-вывода, такие как, например, `php://memory` или `php://temp`.

> php://memory и php://temp являются потоками для чтения/записи и позволяют сохранять временные данные в файлоподобной обертке. Единственная разница между ними заключается в том, что php://memory будет всегда хранить данные в оперативной памяти, тогда как php://temp будет использовать временный файл в том случае, когда объем хранимой информации достигнет заданного лимита (по умолчанию 2 Мб). Расположение этого временного файла определяется аналогично функции sys_get_temp_dir().

Там важно помнить о том, что если стримы закрываются, то их нельзя повторно использовать. А так же после того, как стрим заполнен данными, его необходимо "перемотать" командой `rewind()` для того, чтобы начать из него читать.

[Документация по потокам](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: Подходящий ответ второй, но вопрос еще состаял в том чтобы поменять имя отправляемого файла

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы поменять имя отправляемого файла достаточно добавить параметр `filename`, то есть не объязательно нужно сохранять файл с нужным именем.

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . self::TELEGRAM_TOKEN . "/"
]);

$file = tmpfile();
fwrite($file, json_encode($file_content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

$client->post("sendDocument", [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'chat_id',
            'contents' => self::TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'document',
            'contents' => $file,
            'filename' => 'log.json'
        ]
    ]
]);
```